# Getting printed text to align properly

Tags: java, printf

I'm a totally novice programmer, and I'm pretty confused by how to use printf. The use of printf in my code is at the end of the paymentCalc method; I'm trying to print data to a line, specify 2 decimal points to print, and pad it 10 spaces before printing the next output. 
The code isnt formatting at all. What am I doing wrong here? It's all printing on the same line, but it's printing a million decimals, and it doesnt seem to be padding properly.

```
/*
 * Step 1: Get starting annual interest rate
 * Step 2: Get ending annual interest rate
 * Step 3: Get increment rate
 * Step 4: Get First # of years for repayment
 * Step 5: Get Last # of years for repayment
 * Step 6: Get # of years to increment by
 * Step 7: Get loan amount
 * 
 * Convert annual rates to monthly rates MIR = Annual rate/12
 * MTP = # of years * 12
 * 
 * MIR = monthly interest rate
 * MTP = months to pay
 * Annuity Factor =(mir*(1+mir)^mtp)/(((1+mir)^mtp)-1)
 * Payment = Amount Loaned * Annuity Factor
 * 
 * 
 * Produce a list of possible loan payments
 * Based on a series of annual interest rates
 * Start at user entered rate and increment until it hits user entered max
 * Display annual payment as monthly payments
 *  */


import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;

public class methodshomework {
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);  
  //VARIABLES
  //amounts in years
  double startAnnInt = 0;
  double endAnnInt = 0;
  double incRate = 0;
  double incRatePercent = 0;
  double firstYears = 0;
  double lastYears = 0;
  double incYears = 0;
  double loanAmt = 0;
  //amounts in months
  double startMonthInt = 0;
  double endMonthInt = 0;
  double monthIncRate = 0;
  double firstMonths = 0;
  double lastMonths = 0;
  double incMonths = 0;
  double monthIncRatePercent = 0;
  double annIncRatePercent = 0;

  System.out.println("Hello, and welcome to the loan calculator");
  //Acquire necessary data
  System.out.println("What is the starting annual interest rate? (please enter as XX, where XX = XX%)");
  startAnnInt = (scanner.nextDouble()/100);
  System.out.println("What is the ending annual interest rate? (please enter as XX, where XX = XX%)");
  endAnnInt = (scanner.nextDouble()/100);
  System.out.println("What is the annual increment rate? (please enter as XX, where XX = XX%)");
  incRate = (scanner.nextDouble()/100);
  System.out.println("What is the first term for payment (in years)?");
  firstYears = scanner.nextDouble();
  System.out.println("What is the last term for payment (in years)?");
  lastYears = scanner.nextDouble();
  System.out.println("What is the term increment (in years)?");
  incYears = scanner.nextDouble();
  System.out.println("What is the loan amount? (in the form XXXXXX, where XXXXXX = $XXX,XXX)");
  loanAmt = scanner.nextDouble();


  double[] monthArray = yearToMonth(firstYears, lastYears, incYears, startAnnInt, endAnnInt, incRate);
  firstMonths = monthArray[0];
  lastMonths = monthArray[1];
  incMonths = monthArray[2];
  startMonthInt = monthArray[3];
  endMonthInt = monthArray[4];
  monthIncRate = monthArray[5];
  monthIncRatePercent = monthArray[6];
  annIncRatePercent = monthArray[7];

  paymentCalc(startMonthInt,  endMonthInt,  monthIncRate,  firstMonths,  lastMonths,  incMonths,  loanAmt,  firstYears,  lastYears,  incYears, startAnnInt, endAnnInt, incRate);

}


//MODULES HERE

public static double[] yearToMonth(double firstYears, double lastYears, double incYears, double startAnnInt, double endAnnInt, double incRate){
  double firstMonths = 0;
  double lastMonths = 0;
  double incMonths = 0;
  double startMonthInt = 0;
  double endMonthInt = 0;
  double monthIncRate = 0;
  double monthIncRatePercent = 0;
  double annIncRatePercent = 0;

  //do our conversions
  firstMonths = (firstYears * 12);
  lastMonths = (lastYears * 12);
  incMonths = (incYears * 12);
  startMonthInt = (startAnnInt / 12);
  endMonthInt = (endAnnInt / 12);
  monthIncRate = (incRate / 12);
  monthIncRatePercent = (monthIncRate/100);
  annIncRatePercent = (incRate/100);

  //put our conversions into an array
  double[] monthArray = {firstMonths, lastMonths, incMonths, startMonthInt, endMonthInt, monthIncRate, monthIncRatePercent, annIncRatePercent};

  //return our conversions
  return monthArray;
}


public static void paymentCalc(double startMonthInt, double endMonthInt, double monthIncRate, double firstMonths, double lastMonths, double incMonths, double loanAmt, double firstYears, double lastYears, double incYears, double startAnnInt, double endAnnInt, double incRate){
  double monthInt = 0;
  double monthsToPay = 0;
  double rowNumber = (((lastYears - firstYears))/incYears);
  double rowNumberWithInt = (rowNumber + 1);
  double colNumber = ((endMonthInt - startMonthInt)/monthIncRate);
  double colNumberWithTop = (colNumber+1);
  double currentYears = 0;
  double currentMonths = 0;
  double currentMonthInt = 0;
  double currentPayment = 0;
  double currentAnnInt = 0;
  double annuityAmt = 0;
 //counting columns
  for (double i = 0; i <= colNumberWithTop; i++) {
    //printing the top column
    if (i == 0){
     System.out.printf("%-10s", "Interest Rate");  
     for (double k = 0; k <= rowNumber; k++) {
         currentYears = (firstYears + (incYears * i));
         System.out.printf("%10s", currentYears + " Years"); } 
    } else if (i > 0) {
      //finding annual interest rate for printing, and monthly interest rate as a decimal for math
      currentAnnInt = (startAnnInt + (incRate * i));
      currentMonthInt = ((currentAnnInt/100)/12);
      System.out.printf("%.2f10s\n", (currentAnnInt * 100));
      for (double k = 0; k <= rowNumber; k++) {
           monthsToPay = (startMonthInt + (monthIncRate * i));
           annuityAmt = annuityCalc(currentMonthInt, monthsToPay);
           currentPayment = (loanAmt * annuityAmt);
           System.out.printf("%.2f10s", currentPayment);

      }

    }

    }


     }




public static double annuityCalc(double monthInt, double monthsToPay){
  double annuityFactor = 0;
  double mirPow = 0;
  mirPow = Math.pow((1+monthInt), monthsToPay);
  annuityFactor = ((monthInt*mirPow)/(mirPow-1));
  return annuityFactor;
}

}
```

EDIT:
I changed the code to

```
  for (double i = 0; i <= colNumberWithTop; i++) {
    //printing the top column
    if (i == 0){
     System.out.printf("%10", "Interest Rate");  
     for (double k = 0; k <= rowNumber; k++) {
         currentYears = (firstYears + (incYears * i));
         System.out.printf("%10", currentYears + " Years"); } 
    } else if (i > 0) {
      //finding annual interest rate for printing, and monthly interest rate as a decimal for math
      currentAnnInt = (startAnnInt + (incRate * i));
      currentMonthInt = ((currentAnnInt/100)/12);
      System.out.printf("%10.2f\n", currentAnnInt);
      for (double k = 0; k <= rowNumber; k++) {
           monthsToPay = (startMonthInt + (monthIncRate * i));
           annuityAmt = annuityCalc(currentMonthInt, monthsToPay);
           currentPayment = (loanAmt * annuityAmt);
           System.out.printf("%10.2f", currentPayment);

      }
```

And it's now giving me "java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '1'"

EDIT 2:
I've changed the code to

```
public static void paymentCalc(double startMonthInt, double endMonthInt, double monthIncRate, double firstMonths, double lastMonths, double incMonths, double loanAmt, double firstYears, double lastYears, double incYears, double startAnnInt, double endAnnInt, double incRate){
  double monthInt = 0;
  double monthsToPay = 0;
  double rowNumber = (((lastYears - firstYears))/incYears);
  double rowNumberWithInt = (rowNumber + 1);
  double colNumber = ((endMonthInt - startMonthInt)/monthIncRate);
  double colNumberWithTop = (colNumber+1);
  double currentYears = 0;
  double currentMonths = 0;
  double currentMonthInt = 0;
  double currentPayment = 0;
  double currentAnnInt = 0;
  double annuityAmt = 0;
 //counting columns
 for (double i = 0; i <= colNumberWithTop; i++) {
    //printing the top column
    if (i == 0){
     System.out.printf("%-20s", "Interest Rate");  
     for (double k = 0; k <= rowNumber; k++) {
         currentYears = (firstYears + (incYears * i));
         System.out.printf("%-20s", currentYears + " Years");
     }
     System.out.println(); 
    } else if (i > 0) {
      //finding annual interest rate for printing, and monthly interest rate as a decimal for math
      currentAnnInt = (startAnnInt + (incRate * i));
      currentMonthInt = ((currentAnnInt/100)/12);
      System.out.printf("%-20.2f%%", currentAnnInt*100);
      for (double k = 0; k <= rowNumber; k++) {
           monthsToPay = (firstMonths + (incMonths * i)); 
           annuityAmt = annuityCalc(currentMonthInt, monthsToPay);
           currentPayment = (loanAmt * annuityAmt);
           System.out.printf("%-20.2f", currentPayment);
      }
      System.out.println();

    }

    }


     }
```

The data I'm getting back is

```
Interest Rate                 15.0 Years          15.0 Years          15.0 Years          15.0 Years
                4.25%         28235795.88         28235795.88         28235795.88         28235795.88
                4.50%         26667168.53         26667168.53         26667168.53         26667168.53
                4.75%         25263659.87         25263659.87         25263659.87         25263659.87
                5.00%         24000502.07         24000502.07         24000502.07         24000502.07
                5.25%         22857645.03         22857645.03         22857645.03         22857645.03
                5.50%         21818684.11         21818684.11         21818684.11         21818684.11
                5.75%         20870067.61         20870067.61         20870067.61         20870067.61
                6.00%         20000502.50         20000502.50         20000502.50         20000502.50
                6.25%         19200502.59         19200502.59         19200502.59         19200502.59
>
```

Why on earth is it doing this? It seem to be printing the interest rate under the 30 Years column and shifting all the other columns left one, and printing the first interest rate at the end of the top column

Expected output is

```
Interest Rate    15 Years   20 Years  25 Years  30 Years
4.0000           739.69     605.98    527.84    477.42
4.2500           752.28     619.23    541.74    491.94
4.5000           764.99     632.65    555.83    506.69
4.7500           777.83     646.22    570.12    521.65
5.0000           790.79     659.96    584.59    536.82
5.2500           803.88     673.84    599.25    552.20
5.5000           817.08     687.89    614.09    567.79
5.7500           830.41     702.08    629.11    583.57
6.0000           843.86     716.43    644.30    599.55
```

Comment: "...printing a million decimals..."? Really?  Is is possible you mean 4 decimals instead of 2?

Comment: replace `%.2f10s` with `%10.2f` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Comment: keep the `s` if you want the numbers to be followed by the `s` character

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working; I added an edit with an update

Comment: Can you give the whole stack trace?

Comment: what line is the error? is it `System.out.printf("%10.2f\n", currentAnnInt);`

Comment: If that is the line giving issues then you should replace `\n` with `%n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was that when I asked you to remove the s you removed everywhere...
This should work now

```
for (double i = 0; i <= colNumberWithTop; i++) {
    //printing the top column
    if (i == 0){
     System.out.printf("%-10s", "Interest Rate");  
     for (double k = 0; k <= rowNumber; k++) {
         currentYears = (firstYears + (incYears * i));
         System.out.printf("%10s", currentYears + " Years");
     }
     System.out.println(); 
    } else if (i > 0) {
      //finding annual interest rate for printing, and monthly interest rate as a decimal for math
      currentAnnInt = (startAnnInt + (incRate * i));
      currentMonthInt = ((currentAnnInt/100)/12);
      System.out.printf("%10.2f%%", currentAnnInt*100);
      for (double k = 0; k <= rowNumber; k++) {
           monthsToPay = (startMonthInt + (monthIncRate * i));
           annuityAmt = annuityCalc(currentMonthInt, monthsToPay);
           currentPayment = (loanAmt * annuityAmt);
           System.out.printf("%10.2f", currentPayment);
      }
      System.out.println();
```

*EDITED* per OP's request.

Comment: So the extra println(); is needed to correctly get everything on the right lines?

Comment: Yes, you earlier you had `System.out.printf("%.2f10s\n", (currentAnnInt * 100));` That `\n` would put a new line after printing `currentAnnInt` rate. That's where the rows were breaking. The `println` I put at two places one after header  and one after finishing all the 5 year annuities are printed.

Comment: the math still isn't working properly -- it's giving me 28235795.88 instead of 739.69 in the first cell, for instance, but as far as I can tell my math is right
oh, I see how that works -- thank you for the line fix

Comment: But in your output you posted earlier it was showing fine!

Comment: Also, if I try to left align everything it puts % at the start of each number (ie. if i change %10.2f%% to %-10.2f%%)

Comment: if you want to let align everything then use `"%-10.2f"`

Comment: at any rate, what's going on with the math? i've triple checked it and can't find where the error is

Comment: can you paste the output in the question. You can replace the old output you had in question (which had Interest Rate in first row)

Comment: all of the numbers are wrong, ill replace it now 
EDIT: Alright, I edited it to reflect what I'm getting now

Comment: Checking now and this is for loan amount of 100k right, or is it 1,000,000$ input?

Comment: 100,000 is the input

Comment: Two issues... `monthsToPay = (startMonthInt + (monthIncRate * i));` should be `monthsToPay = (firstMonths + (incMonths * i));` and you should enter input interest rates as **4.25** and **6.25** and not 4.25% or 6.25% or 0.0425 or

Comment: After implementing the fixes, the top column with the years isn't incrementing again (ie. it's displaying 15 for every column). The math is also off again, giving me 418.45 instead of the expected 739.69
Is my program totally off? I'm not sure why it's breaking constantly. If I stop responding now, I'll respond in the morning; I may be heading to bed soon.
I've edited the original post to reflect what it looks like now (edited the code at the bottom)

Comment: Check your variables to know if they are proceeding fine. You've too many confusing variables to track. And you are not using all of them.

Comment: `System.out.printf("%10s", String.Format(currentAnnInt*100, "%.2f")+"%");` try this

Comment: Always print variables as and when you are in doubt. Your math is fine, but variables are not getting used properly.

Comment: When I do that it says cannot find method Format; if I make it String.format, it says double cannot be converted to string, I assume because currentAnnInt*100 is a double. Is there a library I need to import?

Comment: `System.out.printf("%-10s", String.format( "%.2f",currentAnnInt*100)+"%");` try this

Comment: cool! you can upvote the answer too if you liked my timely help :-)

Answer (score 0):

[`PrintStream#printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) takes in a format string and objects, returning a formatted string. The format string has a certain format for numeric values:

> `%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion`

For example, to have a number take up 15 characters and have 2 decimal places, the follow format string would do the job:
`%15.2f`.

In your edit, you are missing the conversion portion of the formatted string. This is causing the `UnknownFormatConversionException`. Each format string MUST end with a conversion (d, f, b, s).

For example, change:

```
System.out.printf("%10", currentYears + " Years");
```

to:

```
System.out.printf("%10s", currentYears + " Years");
```

Notice the `s` at the end of the format string. Read more about the format string syntax at the [official documentation.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)